# Unable to see root API endpoint on Swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ApplicationController {


    @Autowired
    private DBInitializer dbInitializer;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationService service;

    @GetMapping
    public List<ApplicationEntity> getAllNames() {
        return dbInitializer.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/config")
    public String getProperties() {
        return service.getLinks();
    }

}
```

That is my controller. In swagger-ui I am unable to view the

> localhost:8181/api

However, I am able to view the

> localhost:8181/api/config

Can anyone help me to get the base end point on swagger ui.

Thanks in advance !

**Edit added - Swagger configuration**

```
swagger:
    title: DemoApp API
    description: DemoApp API documentation
    version: ${info.build.version:0.0.1}
    termsOfServiceUrl:
    contact:
    license:
    licenseUrl:
    includePattern: "/.*"
```

Comment: Can you please show the console log on app startup?

Answer (score 1):

Try assigining empty string in mapping value like following:

```
@GetMapping(value="")
public List<ApplicationEntity> getAllNames() {
  return dbInitializer.findAll();
}
```

Comment: I can add, however I am still not able to view on swagger. I can view only those endpoints which are starting from "/api/.*"

Comment: How do I select which endpoints to be viewed in my swagger ui

Comment: Can you post your swagger configuration ?

Comment: I have made changes in the question and added swagger config

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it seems there is no functionality on your root mapping i.e. `/api`. Thus you may be getting the below error.

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Jan 29 05:20:59 GMT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

That is because you didn't give any functionality on your root.

If you want to see something when you call root method, you can try declaring a method with same mapping as

```
@GetMapping(value = "")
public String getRoot() {
    // Your logic
}
```

That way when you call `localhost:8181/api`, this method will be called.

Comment: The above comments in previous answer are the same. I have added (value = " "). It works. But I am not able to view on swagger.

Comment: If you can post some screenshots, it will help to understand.